# finding out variables of a trigonometrical function $f$ in dependence of, among others, a local Maxima

Tags: calculus

I have the trigonometrical function $\,f(x)=a\sin(b(x-c))+d\,$. I know that the function has $\,p=\pi\,$ and a local maximum in $\,HP(3|5)\,$.

I want to find out the term of $\,f\,$, i.e. what values $\,a\,$, $b$ $c$ and $d$ has.

**determining first variable:**

I can easily find out the value of $b$ by inserting it in the formula $\,p=\dfrac{2\pi}{b}$. $\Rightarrow$ $b = 2$.

**determining second variable:**

$H(3|5)$ is the local maxima of that function $\Rightarrow$ $f'(3)=0$

$0= 2a * \cos(2(3-c))$

i can divide through $2a$, because a can't be $ 0 $ - otherwise the whole function would be $0$ for every $x$.

$0=cos(2(3-c))$

Now i don't know how to proceed. I don't think, i can substitute $z=6-c$, because $\cos$ varies in dependence of $x$, not $c$.

I also don't think inserting $HP(3|5)$ in $f(x)$ makes sense, because then i have even more variables, and i can't divide $a$ out.

**==> How do i solve this task?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve

$$ cos(2*(3-c)) = 0 $$

You can say that

$$2(3-c) = \pi/2 \pmod \pi .$$

Thus

$$c = 3-\pi/4 \pmod {\pi/2} .$$

Finally you can use $f(3) = 5, f''(3)>0$ to find $a$ and $d$.

Sorry for my ignorance, I wish I could comment but I can't. What does the notation $HP(3|5)$ stand for?

Comment: these are the coordinates for the maximum $x=3,y=5$

Comment: Exactly what @Dr.SonnhardGraubner said.   I don't know if that notation made sense, but HP meant "High Point".

Comment: @Romain And where did you take the $\, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \,$?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean ?

Comment: Why $ 2(3-c) = \pi/2 $ and not e.g. $ 2(3-c) = \pi/8 $? => Did you choose $ \pi/2 $ because its one zero of $\cos(x)$?

Comment: yes, and I choose $ \pi/2 mod \pi$ which is actually all the zeros of cos.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: additionally you have the equation $$f(3)=a\sin(2(3-c))+d=5$$ and $$f'(3)=2a\cos(2(3-c))=0$$